# Keep display metadata value on backend - Custom Metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

I was trying to add a Custom Post type and a Custom Meta box. Which I've done. But I'm facing another problem which is. When I give any value into the Custom Metabox I created its not saving the data on backend. Its perfectly working on Frontend.

Now since its not keeping the value in backend whenever I update the post I have to enter the value each time.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
function news_post_type() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'News', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'News', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit News' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New News' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All News' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View News' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search News' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'Not found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'News'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'This section contains the News section of the site',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
    'has_archive'   => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'news', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_post_type' );
```

and for the metabox :

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'news_date_box' );

function news_date_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'news_date_box',
        __( 'News Date', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'news_date',
        'news',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

function news_date( $post ) {

  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'news_date_content_nonce' );

  echo '<input type="text" id="news_date" name="news_date" placeholder="Enter Date"/>';

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'news_date_save' );

function news_date_save( $post_id ) {

  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
  return;

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['news_date_content_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
  return;

  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
  } else {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;
  }

  $news_date = $_POST['news_date'];
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'news_date', $news_date );
}
```

I searched for the solution but didn't find any and ended up here. I may made a mistake in above code or I have to add additional codes. Any suggestion how to solve this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `news_date()` function to be as follows:

```
function news_date( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'news_date_content_nonce' );

// get the current value of 'news_date' to use in the <input>
$value = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'news_date', true) ;

echo '<input type="text" id="news_date" name="news_date" placeholder="Enter Date" value="' . $value . '"/>';

}
```

Another suggestion would be to change

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'news_date_save' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'save_post_news', 'news_date_save' );
```

and then you're assured that your `news_date_save()` function is only called when a post whose `post_type == 'news'` is saved.

Doing so will allow you to get rid of the `if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {` if/then/else, because then the condition in that `if` will **never** evaluate to true.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Modifying the news_date() function worked.

Thanks again :)